# Why is javascript not recognising an ID tag I've created?

Tags: javascript, element

I've given the element "characterImage" an ID tag but javascript doesn't seem to be recognising that I've given it an ID even though I used (for example) `element.id = "desiredID"`.

The firefox webConsole just keeps returning `document.getElementById(..)` is null" even though I've definetely set an ID and put it within the curly braces

I've tried both the `setAttributeAs()` method and `element.id = "desiredID"`

```
{
let characterImage = document.createElement("IMG");
characterImage.id = "characterImg";
characterImage.src = "Story Game Photos";
characterImage.style.height = "250px";
characterImage.style.height = "250px";
}

function henryFunction(){
document.getElementById("characterImg").src = "Story Game photos/h.jpg";
document.getElementById("characterImg").appendChild(divCharacterImage);
}
```

error message I'm receiving:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Expected result: for javascript to recognise the ID and put my desired picture in its desired place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to append the `image element` to an element in the document. When the element is present in the `DOM` then you can find it using the `id`, using

```
document.getElementById()
```

Add the line

```
 document.querySelector("body").appendChild(characterImage)
```

to append the element to the body tag

```js
function a(){
let characterImage = document.createElement("IMG");
characterImage.id = "characterImg";
characterImage.src = "Story Game Photos";
characterImage.style.height = "250px";
characterImage.style.height = "250px";
document.querySelector("body").appendChild(characterImage)
henryFunction();
}

function henryFunction(){
document.getElementById("characterImg").src = "https://placekitten.com/g/200/300";  
}

a();
```

```html
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing it from `dom` you have to append it to the parent.
So use `.appendChild(divCharacterImage);` befor running `henryFunction();` in your main function.

```
function a(){
    let characterImage = document.createElement("IMG");
    characterImage.id = "characterImg";
    characterImage.src = "Story Game Photos";
    characterImage.style.height = "250px";
    characterImage.style.height = "250px";
    document.querySelector("body").appendChild(characterImage)
    document.getElementById("characterImg").appendChild(divCharacterImage);
    henryFunction();
}

function henryFunction(){
    document.getElementById("characterImg").src = "Story Game photos/h.jpg";
}
```

Just check this update to your code.